# JS - Sorting array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to sort an array of objects in JS, but for some reason it doesnt work :(

This is the code I'm running:

```
let  myArr = [{"name": "a", "age": 21}, {"name": "b", "age": 18}, {"name": "c", "age": 20}];
console.log(myArr.sort((a, b) => {
    return a["age"] > b["age"];
}))
```

The output is the same array as it was declared:

```
[
  { name: 'a', age: 21 },
  { name: 'b', age: 18 },
  { name: 'c', age: 21 }
]
```

When I looked it up it seemed like it's written as it should, not really sure what went wrong.

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: You can use `-` instead of `>`. So that's `myArr.sort((a, b) => a.age - b.age)`. If you want the eldest first, you can use `b.age - a.age`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-` instead of `>`. It should return a `Number` type rather than `Boolean` type. [see sort on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
let myArr = [
  { name: "a", age: 21 },
  { name: "b", age: 18 },
  { name: "c", age: 20 },
];
console.log(
  myArr.sort((a, b) => {
    return a["age"] - b["age"];
  })
);
```

**Using one-liner syntax using `arrow` function**

```js
let myArr = [
  { name: "a", age: 21 },
  { name: "b", age: 18 },
  { name: "c", age: 20 },
];
console.log(myArr.sort((a, b) => a.age - b.age));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Dataset

```
let arr = [
    { name: 'A', age: 40 },
    { name: 'B', age: 50 },
    { name: 'C', age: 30 },
]
```

### Sort: Ascending order on age values

```
arr?.sort((a, b) => {
        return a?.age-b?.age
})
```

### Sort: Descending order on age values

```
arr?.sort((a, b) => {
        return b?.age-a?.age
})
```