# How to sort objects by a property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to sort an array of objects by a property from each object. For example I have this array:

```js
var arr = [{name:"test",kills:4},{name:"test2",kills:1},{name:"test3",kills:7}]
```

I want to change the array so it will be sorted from the object with the max kills to the object with the minimum kills, the result that im looking for is:

```js
[{name:"test3",kills:7},{name:"test",kills:4},{name:"test2",kills:1}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS - Sorting array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66852210/js-sorting-array-of-objects)

Comment: You better use ES6 syntax `let` or `const` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = [{name:"test",kills:4},{name:"test2",kills:1},{name:"test3",kills:7}];
arr.sort((a,b) => b.kills - a.kills)
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [{name:"test",kills:4},{name:"test2",kills:1},{name:"test3",kills:7}];
arr.sort( (a, b) => a.kills < b.kills ? 1 : -1);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This is only correct if the "kills" property of two objects can never be the same. If it can, then this will produce inconsistent results.

Comment: @Pointy Can you prove it?

Comment: Like, create some snippet with an invalid result.

Comment: Yes, easily. Two equal values should have the return value 0. If you don't do that, you're feeding bad data to the sort algorithm. Different browsers (with different sort code) may return different results.